# how to read only committed rows in sql server with spring JPA, in a transaction?

Tags: sql-server, spring-data-jpa

We're developing a new app against an existing sqlserver database. One of the procedures we're reusing is this :

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM mytable WITH (NOLOCK)
```

This is a table with a bunch of pre-generated sequence numbers. We just want to get the next one. This is currently running in a stored procedure. But in our new framework, we may be running this in a distributed environment with multiple servers doing this query. So we thought we needed to remove the 'WITH (NOLOCK)' clause. But when I did that, I noticed that I was getting uncommitted rows back.

The new application is in Spring, and I'm using JPA, and we're doing this query along with other operations, which all need to be wrapped in a transaction. So I tried putting them all in one method, and then adding the

```
@Transactional(isolation = Isolation.READ_COMMITTED)
```

annotation. But this didn't work either, it was still reading uncommitted rows.

Comment: It shouldn't be. How did you determine it's pulling back uncommitted rows?

Comment: It returned a different result when I took off the 'WITH (NOLOCK)'. I thought the TOP 1 meant it was in a certain order. Then when I restored the 'WITH (NOLOCK)', it went back to the first result. So I know it wasn't because that first result wasn't being deleted, either. I don't know how to check if a row is uncommitted.

Comment: `TOP` only limits the number of rows, but that's it. You need an `order by` as well. WIthout an order by, no sql statement can be guaranteed to return in any specific order.

Comment: I did some more testing and it appears you're right; for some reason, I thought the ORDER BY ordered the result set, after the query, and that the TOP inherently did some ordering, perhaps by an index;

Comment: Yeah that's actually a pretty common misconception, worsened by the fact that quite often it DOES return in the order you expect. But under the covers, without an `order by` sql returns data in "whatever order is fastest" which can be by one index, another index, or a complete mess based on a number of different factors (such as whether you're using `nolock`)